# Display what user input but prevent xss

Tags: php, html, xss

I'm trying do a register page, user enter data into input and if that don't match my criteria i want to put his value again in his input box so him don't have to write it again.

I use htmlspecialchars to prevent xss.

```
$string_from_user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['string'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


echo '<input type="text" name="string" value="'.$string_from_user.'">';
```

Problem is...let's say i want to enter name: `john">`
My input box now will show: `john&#34;>`  and the real value of input is: `john&amp;#34;&gt;`

How to make to show my input box to show: `john">` but the real value to be an safe string to prevent xss

**SOLVED**

It seems there was another FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING on my code that i didn't noticed.
I removed and now everything works very well.

```
/* this caused by problems.
$string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'string', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
*/

$string_from_user = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo '<input type="text" name="string" value="'.$string_from_user.'">';
```

Comment: Try to *just* replace `"` with `&quot;`.

Comment: Have you tried just `addslashes()` instead of `htmlspecialchars`? That way hopefully it will be shown correctly in the input box.

Comment: take a look at html Purifier: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @h2ooooooo i would try that, but my `htmlspecialchars` is already replacing `"` with  `&amp;#34;`

Comment: @Quentin no, i'm trying to display back to user the original string him entered, but in the source page must be xss protected

Comment: @PHPCore — Your question seems to be predicated on "the real value" being "the HTML source code" and not "the value displayed to the user" … which is wrong.

Comment: @PHPCore instead of editing question you could post it as answer and accept it.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you need to answer your question below and accept it as the answer. Editing your question with the solution is not permitted. This is **not** a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use **htmlspecialchars_decode**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php refer to the manual for information on usage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$name=htmlentities($name);
echo $name;
```

htmlentities will be converted which you can view it in the pagesource of the page but to the end user it will appear clean

Answer (score 0):

look at this library i think its more powerfull for you

OWASP's antiXSS specific library is at: http://code.google.com/p/php-antixss/

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was another FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING on my code that i didn't noticed.
I removed and now everything works very well.

```
/* this caused by problems.
$string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'string', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
*/

$string_from_user = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo '<input type="text" name="string" value="'.$string_from_user.'">';
```